# If app only targets Android 4.0 and up, can v4 support library be removed from project?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-version, android-support-library

I've written an app that only targets Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) and up. `android-support-v4.jar` seems to be a dependency in my Eclipse project by default. Since I'm not targetting any lower than 4.0, can I remove this support library as a dependency, because it is not needed...? I don't want any unnecessary bloat being packaged with my application (correct me if that's not actually how it works).

If so, how does one remove it in Eclipse? I can't seem to find an option anywhere.

Comment: Note that the "4" in "v4 support library" refers to the [Android API level](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels) 4, not the Android version 4.0. API level 4 actually corresponds to Android 1.6 aka Donut.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Just delete the jar, and if you don't have any other dependencies the whole libs/ folder.

Comment: Deleting the jar from `/libs` doesn't seem to persist. Every time I do something like add a new Activity class it adds the jar back in.

Comment: If you use the ADT wizard, it probably does... Just make sure you remove it before exporting your final APK. Or use ProGuard it will strip any unused library code even if the jar is there.

Comment: If you're using a ViewPager in your app, you'll have to leave it in. The ViewPager is only available in the Support Library.

Comment: Ah, yes. There is that. But if he didn't get any errors after removing, he probably isn't.

Answer (score 1):

**uncheck create icon** and **uncheck create activity**, when you create a new android application project.  In this way, adt will not import support library, and the application template just finished.